# How to print data in a corresponding row

Tags: excel

I have 6 columns, A-F accordingly. I am trying to come up with a formula that will do the following psuedocode (using i as a placeholder for row number):
 if(A[i] is in column E print the value in the cell in row F that is directly next to it in row D) For example, if cells A12 and E12 match, cell F12 is printed to column D. I am a beginner at excel and any help is much appreciated. This is the formula I currently have that doesn't work:

```
=IF(A2 =$E:$E, VLOOKUP(A2,$E:$E, 4, FALSE), "")
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this is the formula you need, enter it in `D2` and fill down column `D`:

```
D2
=VLOOKUP(A2, E:F, 2, FALSE)
```